# estimateRigidTransform on dense optical flow in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I am trying to implement the algorithm described by Wand and Adelson (1993) in the paper [Layered Representation for Motion Analysis](http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/wang_tr221.pdf), a summary of the paper can be found in any lecture on Computer Vision, [this one](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~lazebnik/research/spring08/lec22_optical_flow.pdf) is from the CS department at the University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, starting at slide 53:

- Compute local flow in a coarse-to-fine fashion
- Obtain a set of initial affine motion hypotheses

  - Divide the image into blocks and estimate affine motion parameters in each block by least squares

    - Eliminate hypotheses with high residual error
  - Perform k-means clustering on affine motion parameters

    - Merge clusters that are close and retain the largest clusters to obtain a smaller set of hypotheses to describe all the motions in the scene
- Iterate until convergence:

  - Assign each pixel to best hypothesis

    - Pixels with high residual error remain unassigned
  - Perform region filtering to enforce spatial constraints
  - Re-estimate affine motions in each region

---

Since I am using OpenCV to implement the algorithm, it only makes sense to use the built in functions to do so. And the most meaningful function is [estimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform), from the documentation:

> Computes an optimal affine transformation between two 2D point sets.

and the output looks something like this:

[image: estimateRigidTransformOutput]

The description of the affine model in the **slides** looks like:

[image: Affine Model]

This model is of course consistent with the description in the paper (and everywhere else).

1. If I want to try and map the output of the function to the given model, the only explanation would be that a_1 and a_4 map to b_1 and b_2. **Is this intuition correct? and following from this does it make sense that a_3 = -a_5?**
2. Knowing that the output of [calcOpticalFlowFarneback](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) is a flow matrix following the relationship:

   [image: flowRelationship]

   **What is the form of the input that should be used to get the correct the results from the estimateRigidTransform function? and how is it possible to calculate the residuals after the estimation?**
3. **Finally, am I considering the wrong function to calculate the affine transforms?**

Comment: you'll have to set `fullAffine=false` in estimateRigidTransform and keep in mind that computing the rigid transform in openCV invokes some kind of RANSAC already instead of a transformation optimization over ALL provided point samples. As far as I see it, your assumptions in  `1.` are right (if fullAffine == false).

Comment: Thank you @Micka so from your answer I understand that the last question is also answered since the function is the correct one. And for the second question, should I do the estimation on the prev data and the calculated next data using the flow matrix? or should i use it only on prev and next and then the calculated next is used for residuals?

Comment: no idea, sorry. But as I said, be careful that there is no problem in using estimateRigidTransform from openCV because they use a RANSAC inside which might or might not be a problem in your method.

Comment: in addition to your assumptions, it should be `a_2 == a_6`

Comment: @Micka I thought it uses Least Squares, I should look into that. Thank you

Comment: have a look at the comments of http://answers.opencv.org/question/10672/estimaterigidtransform-returns-non-sensical-values/ but no idea whether there was changed anything between opencv versions. Maybe you can adapt the openCV code easily to use a plain least squares optimization. Typically at the end of a ransac there is performed a least squares opt. of all inliers, maybe you just adapt/use that.

Comment: @MahdiChamseddine were you able to implement the algorithm from Wand et al using opencv? If so, could you please post your code?

Comment: @SrikarAppalaraju unfortunately I cannot remember.. this work has been a while ago and during my previous employment.. I am sorry, even if I did, I no longer have access to that code.